# mergExt - localizing app with mergSettings on iOS

Tags: ios, livecode

I'm localizing my iOS app and having difficulty translating strings in the mergSettings extension for LiveCode. I setup a new folder - ja.lproj. Then, I made a new file called "Localizable.strings" inside of that folder. I then created "key" = "value"; pairs. I loaded the app and the strings were not translated.

Any ideas on what to try next? Monte?

Answer (score 0):

The settings bundle has it's own localized resources folders so ja.lproj needs to be inside Settings.bundle. Also I'm assuming when you loaded the app the locale was set to ja?

---

EDIT

The file should be named Root.strings

Comment: Yes, I put ja.lproj in Settings.bundle. What's the difference between locale and language? I changed language to JA, but I don't know how to change locale?

Comment: Hmm... that should change it. Are you seeing the same thing in Settings.app as InAppSettingsKit?

Comment: I see just the English settings InAppSettingsKit and the Settings.app. Here's a screenshot if that helps. [Screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jx64gjw667tp3c6/Settings_JA%20test.png)

Comment: Ah, sorry I didn't pick this up earlier the file should be named Root.strings

Comment: Changed the name to Root.strings in the ja.lproj subfolder. I tested on simulator and device with same result. When I initially opened the Root.strings in en.lproj there were only 4 lines of code: `
"Group" = "Group"; 
"Name" = "Name";
"none given" = "none given";
"Enabled" = "Enabled";` So I added the rest of the string pairs from the ja.lproj>Roots.string file with the appropriate english pair. Could it be a problem in the Root.plist if the string pairs were not automatically generated?

Comment: Hmm... I'm not sure what's going on. Can you email me the Settings.bundle